# Remove some java files from jacoco test coverage using gradle

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, jacoco, test-coverage

I want to exclude some source files in Jacaco Test coverage report.For other generated code I have done like this:

```
classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug/com",
            excludes: [
                    '**/R.class',
                    '**/R$*.class']
                    )
```

But for excluding Java files when I am trying to do like this:

```
   dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug/com",
            excludes: [
                 'src//java/com/example/application/Constants.java']
```

have also tried like this:  `'**/application/Constants.class'`.It doesn't work. Do I need to include the path here:  `dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug/com"`?

I am using Android studio 3.0 (i don't think it matters here). Full code that I am trying:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {
        group = "Reporting"
        description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"
        reports {
            xml.enabled = true
            html.enabled = true
        }

 sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets)

 classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug/com",
            excludes: [
                    'src//java/com/example/application/Constants.java',     //this is not working
                    '**/R.class',
                    '**/R$*.class',
                    '**/BuildConfig.*',
                    '**/Manifest*.*',
                    '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                    '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                    '**/*$Lambda$*.*', // Jacoco can not handle several "$" in class name.
                    '**/*Module.*', // Modules for Dagger.
                    '**/*Dagger*.*', // Dagger auto-generated code.
                    '**/*MembersInjector*.*', // Dagger auto-generated code.
                    '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',
                    '**/*_Factory.*', //Dagger auto-generated code
                    '**/*$*$*.*', // Anonymous classes generated by kotlin
                    //add libraries
                    'android/**/*.*',
                    'com/**/*.*',
                    'uk/**/*.*',
                    'io/**/*.*',
                    //remove what we don't test
                    'androidTest/**/*.*',
                    'test/**/*.*',
                    '**/injector/**/*.*',
                    '**/model/**/*.*',
                    '**/mock/**/*.*',
                    '**/event/**/*.*',
                    '**/**_ViewBinding**',
                    '**/*EventType.*',
                    '**/**Mocked'
            ]

    )
    executionData = fileTree(dir: 'build/jacoco', include: '**/*.exec')

}
```

Comment: Hi, you tried using class file like this: `'**/application/Constant.class'`, but your  source file is named `Constants.java`. So did you also try without this typo? e.g. `'**/Constants.class'` ?

Comment: yes I tried without the typo as well

Answer (score 5):

In my project, config like this:

```
//exclude the folders we do not want to check
jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [
                    '**/enum/**',
                    '**/util/**',
            ])
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: can we add multiple classDirectories? I wasn't able to do so!

Comment: @Shubham off cause you can, just add the package path to the list, like `'**/enum/**'` in the code.

Comment: it will be great if you can give an example. with both class and java files excluded from intermediate and source directories.

Answer (score 4):

`classDirectories` of task of type `JacocoReport` is about **`class`** files, not `java` source files. And I'm pretty sure that your directory

> ```
>  classDirectories = fileTree(
>             dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug/com",
> ```

contains `class` files and does not contain `java` files. Also as you can see other patterns are about `class` files:

> ```
>                 '**/R.class',
>                 '**/R$*.class',
> ```

And that's why your exclusion

> ```
>            'src//java/com/example/application/Constants.java',     //this is not working
> ```

doesn't work. So change it to match existing `class` file in given directory.

Also note that you can easily debug result of `fileTree(...)` call by simply printing it:

```
tree.each {File file ->
    println file
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I even tried using class file like this: '**/application/Constant.class'. What does ** refer to. As per my understanding, it refers to anything inside package. This doen't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Shubham I already explained how you can debug result of `fileTree`, so please debug it. And IMO without **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** from you that **fully demonstrates** your problem, there is nothing more to say that could help you, especially that similar configuration works fine for others.

Comment: @Godin How to do this on a source set since someone may plugin generated code plugins adding to the source sets?

Answer (score 1):

For gradle 6+ you configure it like below:

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            includes = ['com/myapp/*']
            excludes = [
                    'com/myapp/folderToExclude1/*',
                    'com/myapp/folderToExclude2/*',
            ]
           limit {
                minimum = 0.85
            }
        }
    }
}
```